# DL windowed envelopes: modify header and margins

Tags: header-footer

I am using the `lettre` `class` https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/lettre wich is very convenient for letters that have to fit DL windowed envelopes. Then the *To adress* fits perfectly the envelope window.

But I have difficulties to modify the header such as shown on the picture below.

[image]

I would like to add a logo and custom parameters on it's right and also give a smaller margin to the body of the letter.

I've been trying to play with the default.ins file but without much success. I don't have a good understanding of what parameters to modify. Would someone have an idea?

Here is the current code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,origdate]{lettre}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mltex}

\begin{document}


\begin{letter}{ To Name \\ 
                To Street \\ 
                ZIP \& City \\  
                ~ \\  
                ~ }
\lieu{City}


\pagestyle{plain}

\name{Dr~Lorem Ipsum}

\conc{This is the object } 

\opening{Dear Lorem Ipsum,}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

\closing{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.} 

\end{letter}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: The logo portion can be remedied with `\setstackEOL{\\}\address{\includegraphics[height=2cm,width=2cm]{example-image}
  \sffamily\Longstack[l]{Name\\Website\\Mail\\Tel}}\telephone{}\fax{}` (needs `graphicx` and `stackengine` packages).

Comment: Thx for answer. I added the stackengine package through MikTex but I get an "unknown command" for both \setstackEOL and \Longstack. Where could that come from?

Comment: Apparently, your system does not currently have the `stackengine` package available.  You can download the style file and documentation at http://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine.  In the short term, you can place it in your working directory, though you should find the proper place to install the package in the long term.

Comment: Ok thx I have now the stackengine package working. But I dont see any difference when compiling the new code. I edited my post with Steven B. Segletes solution. Did I do a mistake in the code?

Comment: ok, I had made a mistake,  the \address{} shouldle be after \begin{letter} and not \begin{document}. Thank you very much Steven B. Segletesn the result is great! Maybe you could add it as a solution?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Do you want to write up an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I remedied the log portion by defining `\address` as an `\includegraphics` followed by a `\Longstack`, and turning off `\telephone` and `\fax`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,origdate]{lettre}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mltex}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\setstackEOL{\\}

\begin{letter}{ To Name \\ 
                To Street \\ 
                ZIP \& City \\  
                ~ \\  
                ~ }

\address{\includegraphics[height=2cm,width=2cm]{example-image}
\sffamily\Longstack[l]{Name\\Website\\Mail\\Tel}}

\telephone{}\fax{}

\lieu{City}


\pagestyle{plain}

\name{Dr~Lorem Ipsum}

\conc{This is the object } 

\opening{Dear Lorem Ipsum,}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

\closing{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.} 

\end{letter}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]